# Why does my single line batch file require user input on deleting files on a drive?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a batch for a scheduled task to purge a drive every 6 days. The goal is to have it fully automated so I can schedule it and walk away. For some reason my batch keeps asking for user input (y/n) which defeats the purpose.

```
REM Friday Purge
forfiles /p "G:" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del G:"
```

Why does my batch file with just a single line (without remark line) require user input on deleting files on drive `G:` on execution?

Comment: Look at the output of `del /?` and you will find what you need.

Comment: Not understanding why you are using FORFILES for this task?

Comment: I was origionally going to purge a select file holding old backups but I can really purge the root and not have to worry about files. I fell like ECHO Y  needs to be in after del / but am not sure how to set up an Echo.

Sorry I am such a .bat rookie!
-Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/F` switch will force delete a read-only file.
The `/Q` will prevent the message from popping up.
The `/S` will delete all files in directories as well.
THE `RD` will remove a folder.

Therefore; your new code should look like this:

```
del /f /q /s *.*
del /f /q /s G:
```

BONUS

If you want this to be automated:

```
for %%i in (Mon) do (
if "%date:~0,3%"=="%%i" goto yes
)
goto endlocal 
:yes
del /f /q /s G:
del /f /q /s G:\*.*
:endlocal
```

This will check if the day of the week is Monday, and do this once very 7 days. This checks the day and does the schedule part for you; so set it to run everyday.

Comment: I noticed it deletes everything but a windows backup (of files on my C drive). This is what takes up the most space. I have a funny feeling it is simply windows being windows.

Comment: I think Andy is right. The Windows Backup utility has a tendency to make it very hard to delete a backup folder. It's not just the read-only attribute. I think it uses access control lists (ACLs). This can be overcome but needs more investigation.